# how to get selectbox value name in action of zend controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a select box in a zend form which is filled from database

```
$topics = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Model_Topic')->findAll();
$topic = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('topic');
$topic->setLabel('Topic')->setRequired(true);

foreach($topics as $topics1) {
   $topic->addMultiOption($topics1->id, $topics1->title);
}
```

in action I can get the value like `$topic =$form->getValue('topic');` this will give me the ID but how can I get the name of that ID?

Comment: You have been a member for over 2 years now. I *really* find it hard to believe that you still don't know how to format your posts.

Comment: am rarely use this forum... can you tell me how to accept the answer.. i did not see any option to accept answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the option "value" (as in the text value) by getting the entire set of multi-options and picking the selected one by the array key

```
$topic = $form->getValue('topic');
$options = $form->topic->getMultiOptions();
$topicTitle = $options[$topic];
```